What is the origin (and perhaps original) of this quote by André Weil
I found this quote by André Weil in a few places online:

As every mathematician knows, nothing is more fruitful than these obscure analogies, these indistinct reflections of one theory into another, these furtive caresses, these inexplicable disagreements; also nothing gives the researcher greater pleasure... The day dawns when the illusion vanishes; intuition turns to certitude; the twin theories reveal their common source before disappearing; as the Gita teaches us, knowledge and indifference are attained at the same moment. Metaphysics has become mathematics, ready to form the material for a treatise whose icy beauty no longer has the power to move us.

But never with a source or (if it was originally written in French) the original French.
I'm looking for a source and especially (if this is a translation) the original.

A. Weil, De la métaphysique aux mathématiques, Collected Papers, Vol. 2, Springer-Verlag, 1980, pp.408-412.
(Translation into English in J. Gray, Open Univ. Course in History of Math., Unit 12, p. 30.$)$
Found these references in a book by I. Kleiner, Excursions in the History
of Mathematics, by Springer.
